# --no-wait tag not working when using az resource delete

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I am trying to delete a virtual machine using the command below

```
az resource delete --ids /subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-111111111111/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualMachines/vmlname1 --no-wait
```

I am getting this error:

```
unrecognized arguments: --no-wait
```

When I remove **--no-wait** it works

By this link:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-delete-optional-parameters
```

no-wait is given as a valid parameter

```
--no-wait
Do not wait for the long-running operation to finish.
```

Can anyone tell me, whether it is possible to use --no-wait in az resource delete ?

**Update:**
This is the az cli version i am using:

```
{
  "azure-cli": "2.40.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.40.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.8",
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the `--no-wait` flag with the `az resource delete` command. My testing using the flag did not produce the error that you are seeing. Is it possible that your azure cli is not up to date?

You can upgrade your azure cli to the latest version by following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/update-azure-cli).

Answer (score 0):

**I have reproduced in my environment and got below results:**

I have one VM named **`srivm`** with **Resource ID** like below:

[image]
When I ran the same command as you to delete VM, I got **same error** as below:

```bash
az resource delete --ids /subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualMachines/<vmname> --no-wait
```

**Response:**

[image]

Note that, the current version of the Azure CLI is **2.43.0**. The error may occur if the `CLI version` is less than **latest** version.

When I checked the **`az version`**, I got **response** like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, upgrade your CLI version to latest version with `az upgrade` command or download `azure-cli-2.43.0.exe` directly.

After installing the **latest version**, I'm able to delete the VM successfully after running below command:

```bash
az resource delete --ids /subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualMachines/<vmname> --no-wait
```

**Response:**

[image]
To **confirm** that, I checked Portal and VM deleted successfully like below:

[image]